# How to put cells in GridX in always-edit mode?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

I'm using Dojo 1.9 with GridX 1.2. I'd like to provide checkbox in grid, which could be easily clicked, changing the value of the boolean field in data mode. I'd like to use it, for example, for selection.

Currently, the checkbox shows up only after double click, then it must be clicked once again. So the 3 clicks are needed to check the state of the checkbox. It provides bad user experience, and decreases the efficiency of using the grid.

Is it possible to tell, that the checkbox would be always rendered in ready-to-click state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can done via parameter `alwaysEditing`. Unfortunately, I haven't found example showing it, but you can modify the example `test_edit_grid.js` from `test` directory from gridx distribution.

The example code with use case looks so:

```
    { field: "Heard", name:"Check Box", width: '30px', editable: true,
        alwaysEditing: true,
        editor: "dijit.form.CheckBox",
        editorArgs: {
            props: 'value: true'
        }
    },
```

Comment: I am applying alwaysEditing=true for No of Columns the Pointer is always focusing the last column even if i select any other column in the Grid.